# Windows 8 phone app linking to other downloaded applications and store

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, hyperlink

I would like my app to link to other installed apps on the users phone, such as facebook. Once they click the icon/button it should switch from my app to the selected app, the code should check that app is on their phone. If it is open the app, if it is not open the store page, for that app so they can download it.

Is there a way to link or to navigate to the app? or store? (c# and XAML).

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: Which 'different ways', how did they fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is URI for the app. It will open the app for you and if the app is not available. It will automatically take the user to the store so that he can download it. This will only work if that app has a Uri available.

[Here](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/URI_Association_Schemes_List) and [Here](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Apps_with_undocumented_URI_schemes) is a list of apps that support Uri scheme

For example, You can open Facebook App by this code

```
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("fb:"));
```